# new window appears under main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing an application using WPF. I would like such an action: when I press down mouse button on a button, another window appears, when I release mouse button wherever, this window hides. That is my code so far:

XAML:

```
<Button Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="button_wykres" PreviewMouseUp="button_wykres_PreviewMouseUp" PreviewMouseDown="button_wykres_PreviewMouseDown">
```

C#:

```
private void button_wykres_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        omww.Top = this.Top+50;
        omww.Left = this.Left +180;
        omww.Show();
    }

    private void button_wykres_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        omww.Hide();
    }
```

The problem is that new window (omww) appears under the main one, but I need it on top. When I tried other events, i.e. button.Click window is showed above the old one, as I want, and that confuses me. However, Click event doesn't meet my needs. I'd be grateful if anybody help me.

Comment: check the `ShowActivated`property.
Or call the `Activate` method. Or do not use the Preview event. The next problem seems to be that you show the wndow and hide it immediatly.

Comment: why do you need two windows, going by your question user will not be able to do anything on window2 (omww) as it will be gone the moment user releases the mouse button?

Comment: @RicoW use a `Popup` to show what you're showing in your `Window`? If you have another `Window` and get it activated/focus to it to get it to be front, it would most likely trigger the `PreviewMouseUp` on the first window immediately so all you'd end up seeing is a flicker. Using a Popup you should be able to get your requirement fine.

Comment: what i wanted to say is what does your window2 do? why do you need it? Is it showing the readonly info about anything or what?

Comment: @RicoW If you want to stick with your idea, try setting `omww.Topmost = true;` just after `omww.Show();` in your `PreviewMouseDown` event

Comment: Thanks for your advises. Viv, Topmost property works perfectly, this is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two possible options for making the child `Window` appear on top of the parent `Window`. The first was mentioned by @Viv in a comment and that is to set the `TopMost` property on the child `Window` to `true`:

```
omww.Topmost = true;
```

The second option would be to set the `Owner` property of the child `Window` to the parent `Window` (if there is a direct relationship between them):

```
omww.Owner = this; // if called from the parent Window code behind
```